# When exactly are you detected as the pursuer in multiplayer?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

When my pursuer is doing silly things in front of me, he's detected and a red arrow appears above his head.
But how to know when a red arrow is pointed on *your* head? Does it appear as soon as the controller is vibrating (ie when you're running and in your target's sight) or does it need more indiscreet actions?
And when to know when it disappears as it seems to disappear after a given time for your pursuers, even if you keep them in sight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're pursuing someone, next to their picture on the right is a little blue gauge. If that gauge drops at all, you'll have a little red arrow over your head, because you're doing something that makes you noticeable.

Comment: So this gauge should also fill again over time as the arrow disappear after a few seconds. I'll take a closer look at the gauge when running after my prey, and see how it react afterwards before accepting the answer.

Comment: OK, gauge is refilling (quite quickly but it seems to depend if you're still in sight or not). Further test to be done but it seems to be the right direction. Accepted then! Thanks.